# Monitoring system for server/client application

Tags: monitoring, zeromq

I have to develop a monitoring system, which will monitor the Server/Client application. The major task which the monitoring system needs to perform is

> 1) Keep the track of the Connection bewtween Server/ Client
>
> 2)Visualize the CPU usage of the server or client.
>
> 3) Memory Usage
>
> and some others also.

I don't know which software will be useful for this purpose. I searched on net and found that ZeroMQ can be good for this. Can anyone direct me in a good way, or at least tell me from where to start. I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: This question would be better served at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an application monitoring tool, you can checkout nagios.